# cast datetime to date

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I'm doing a `whereBetween` dates query on Eloquent. However, I have an issue with the date time.

If I select `date_from to 2018-11-01` and `date_to to 2018-11-29`
and if I have a data that was created on `2018-11-29 12:28:45` the data created on this datetime will not be included because of the time.

Is there a way to cast the `created_at` to `date`?

here's my code:

```php
Payable::with('details', 'transaction_type')
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$request->date_from, $request->date_to])
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set time to your date variables.

```
$request->date_from = $request->date_from . ' 00:00:00';
$request->date_to = $request->date_to . ' 23:59:59';
```

Comment: that solved the issue.. thanks a lot.., but do you think it is possible to cast the `created_at` to date?

Comment: created_at is the default column of the laravel. When you insert a record to database, it set via laravel eloquent model.

If you want change it format, you can use laravel's mutators method. Please check detail laravel's official page. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators

Answer (score 0):

I feel a much cleaner way to handle dates in Laravel is using the Carbon package.

```
$date_from = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->date_from)->startOfDay();
$date_to = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->date_to)->endOfDay();
```

Just FYI, `created_at` column when accessed via eloquent will return a carbon date object by default.

Hope this helps.

K

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding an extra `->` to your querying, you can very easily do this:

```
Payable::with('details', 'transaction_type')
         ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $request->date_from)
         ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $request->date_to)
         ->get();
```